# Print binary output in knitr

Tags: knitr

Just showing an example to represent my seemingly simple problem.

i generate a variable with random TRUE/FALSE.

```
<<>>=
data <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1, replace = TRUE)
@
```

Somewhere in the TeX (knitr), i need to print whether its TRUE or FALSE.

```
\Sexpr{!is.na(data)}
```

but my text output is **blank**. I am not sure whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
<<>>=
data <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1, replace = TRUE)
@

\Sexpr{data}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks R. Schumacher. This works. Now how about for variables with NA? Can I display Exists / NA if the variable has a value other than NA, or print NA?

Comment: I suspect that this can be done, but because of the specific issues in dealing with NA in R this question will get a better answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r