# Display if the variable is NA / not-NA

Tags: knitr

I have a variable assigned as a output of a function, which returns numeric value or NA. The following code mimics it.

```
<<>>=
data <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1, replace = TRUE)
@
```

Somewhere in the TeX (knitr), i need to print whether the output is VALID or NA. I try to do it like this

```
\Sexpr{!is.na(data)}
```

but my text output is blank. Note that I don't need to print the numeral value, just VALID / NA. Any hints?

Comment: This question was posted somewhere else (or maybe here but a different question), but I forget where. Can you please link to your other question?

Comment: Thanks  scottkosty.  I had asked a similar question earlier. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260994/. Not quite the same.

Comment: Still looking for an answer :|

Comment: For me the output has TRUE where the `Sexpr` is. Can you please post a minimal `.Rnw` example?